# PHP if(){} does not echoes vars got from html

Tags: php, html, get, gettype

All I need is: 
1. After pressing 'submit' button to get vars to function and use return value.
2. To understand why I can not echo functions return value;

**PHP FUNCTION:**

```
function check_if_numbers($x, $y)
{   
        $permission =0;
        if((gettype($x)==gettype($y))&&(gettype($x)=="integer")) {return 1;}
        else {return 0;}
}
```

**PHP CODE**

```
<?php
    if( isset($_GET['submit']) )
    {
        $x = htmlentities($_GET['x']);
        $y = htmlentities($_GET['y']);
        $permission_token=check_if_numbers($x, $y);
        echo $permission_token;
    }
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="get">
Determine X = <input name='x' id='x' type="text" size="1"></br>
Determine Y = <input name='y' id='y' type="text" size="1"></br>
<font size=2 >Input only integers</font>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
```

Comment: Why you are not using `is_numeric()` function?

Comment: What makes you think you can't use an `echo` statement?

Comment: `chek_if_numbers($x, $y)` and `check_if_numbers($x, $y)`, capisce?

Comment: `$permission_token=chek_if_numbers($x, $y);` Typo in calling your function?

Comment: What is the purpose of $permission in check_if_numbers()?

Comment: if value 0  breaks; if value 1 then something happens next;

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to name your submit button, that's why `$_GET['submit']` is never set:

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
```

Remove these closing `</input>` - they are all incorrect.

Comment: Now echo outputs 0. My If statement does not change value to 1.

Comment: Form data is always `STRING`, so it will never be `=="integer"` in your `gettype()` check.

Comment: @user2361662 You're new around here, so an advice: you should *accept* the answer if it answered your question (and it did). :-)

Comment: Correct. Any suggestions how to remake my input security wall to capture only integers?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/function.is-int.php  and http://www.php.net/manual/function.settype.php

Answer (score 1):

A `c` is missing when you call `chek_if_numbers` and not `check_if_numbers`.

Answer (score -1):

> 2 To understand why I can not echo functions return value;

For old versions of PHP (before 4.3 I think), PHP will echo zero (ie `echo(0);`) as boolean false and not 0, and as such it will not display anything on the screen.

Comment: "PHP will not display an echo'd integer" ... ;) ... Really???

Comment: Why wouldn't `echo` display an integer?

Comment: I meant it is zero.  This has stumped me before.  Try it your self.

Comment: PHP even echos `0` ...

Comment: @djot.  It will echo false which it blank.

Comment: I just tried it, it *does* echo `0`. What it doesn't echo is `false`.

Comment: @Cucu and djot.  Depends which version of PHP you are using.

Comment: You are getting your booleans and integers mixed up

Comment: "My" PHP echos integers correctly ;)

Comment: See http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/6918-echoing-integer-0-zero for someone who had this problem in previous PHP versions.

Comment: @user1032531 And maybe upgrade your PHP if you're using an 8 year old version. ;-) At least the issue you linked is 8 years old.